# resx files with Custom Extensions

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, localization, cultureinfo

I am using custom resources to manage my information on a site with the following Properties for the resx files

1. Build Action: Embedded Resource
2. Custom  Tool: PublicResXFileCodeGenerator

Resource File names are the following.

- Resource.fr.FR.resx (French version of a website for France)
- Resource.fr-BE.resx (French version of a website for Belgium)
- Resource.resx  (Fallback resource)

This works fine, but when I try to add a custom resoure as such

- Resource.ja-BE.resx (Japanese version of a website for Belgium)

The PublicResXFileCodeGenerator generates a C# code behind for this and thinks its a new fallback resource for something else. I am guessing that the tool reasons that this is not a valid Culture and therefore it is behaving that way.

**How do you get around this and allow the declaration of a custom resource in this way, or is there a different way I should be going about this problem?**

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172469.aspx explains how to create a custom culture, although i question the reasoning behind making up new cultures such as japanese in belgium.

Comment: @Till I dont have a problem creating a custom culture. I have an issue with declaring a custom resource. Custom Cultures are possible but the default behaviour of the PublicResXFileCodeGenerator is not to acknowledge them ... maybe I need to register the CultureInfo so that the PublicResXFileCodeGenerator can pick it up.

Comment: Your ja-BE culture should be correctly recognized after following the instructions in the link i posted.

Comment: Oh I see you need to register the culture before PublicResXFileCodeGenerator is able to pick it up. Gosh thats dirty ... add as an answer and I will mark it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create and register your culture using the information found at [this msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172469.aspx) and your ResourceManager should correctly recognize your resource file.

Comment: The link appears to be broken